# Why Apache Ignite (version 2.3.0) Spark SharedRDD forgot some (20-30%) of entries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ignite

I have a Spark Cluster in Docker with 1 Master and 2 Workers. On every worker an Apache Ignite Software running.

If I open spark-shell and execute the following command( where I open the cache store some value and read out the data from the cache):

```
import org.apache.ignite.spark._
import org.apache.ignite.configuration._
val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration())
val sharedRDD: IgniteRDD[Integer, Integer] = ic.fromCache[Integer, Integer]("partitioned")
sharedRDD.savePairs(sc.parallelize(1 to 100, 10).map(i => (i, i)))
sharedRDD.count
```

then I receive:

```
res3: Long = 100
```

If I execute `sharedRDD.collect().foreach(println)`, there are every number pairs in the list unil 100

```
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
(4,4)
(5,5)
(6,6)
(7,7)
(8,8)
(9,9)
(10,10)
...
(100,100)
```

It's perfect.

**BUT** When I quit with sys.exit and reopen the spark-shell again, and execute the following code (where I read out the data from the cache):

```
import org.apache.ignite.spark._
import org.apache.ignite.configuration._
val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration())
val sharedRDD: IgniteRDD[Integer, Integer] = ic.fromCache[Integer, Integer]("partitioned")
sharedRDD.count
sharedRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

Then the result is

```
res0: Long = 60
```

and some number pairs are missing. (for example 4,9,10)

```
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
(5,5)
(6,6)
(7,7)
(8,8)
(11,11)
(12,12)
(13,13)
(14,14)
(15,15)
...
```

Has anybody an idea why this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue that causes nodes embedded into executors started in server mode [1], most likely this is the reason. As a workaround you can force `IgniteContext` to start everything in client mode:

```
val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration().setClientMode(true))
```

Of course, this assumes that you start in a standalone mode with a separately running Ignite cluster.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5981